# how to view help document in R windows just like the way in linux?

Tags: r

I would like to know how to view `R` help document in windows, just like the way it is when using Linux. That is to say, the help document is shown in the same terminal of the running `R` program; within it I just type `?help` command.

Comment: This sounds like a poor workflow style -- you're mixing a reference page with your operations page.  Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft: I find it handy because you don't have to switch windows. I type `?topic`, navigate the document, search it, copy commands, etc., then press "q" to get back to the R command line. It's very quick and my fingers never leave the keyboard.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich I see your point, more or less.  Alt-Tab could get you to the "other" window and back about as easily.

Answer (score 3):

`options(help_type="text")` will pop up a text window within R, rather than displaying help in the browser. You can't actually display help inside the R console, though. (Not even when using the console versions of R, strangely enough.)

Comment: It's not really that strange that you can't display text in the Windows Rterm console. The Windows R console is a very different program than the *nix and Mac consoles.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use one of the many R GUI environments available on Windows--these generally provide docs in the same "window" (thought not in the R terminal itself). If that's close enough for you, try [RStudio](http://www.rstudio.com) or [RKWard](http://rkward.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: This sounds like the opposite of what is requested by the OP.